# Getting contenteditable div's current value and update database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update, contenteditable

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create editable database interface. I have got checkboxes in every row and an edit button. I need to update table(in database) when button clicked(rows that are checked). However I can't get current values in cells. I tried contentedittable div to display attiributes.

```
<?php  while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="need_delete[<?php echo $rows['UniqueID']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[<?php echo $rows['UniqueID']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['UniqueID']; ?>"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div contenteditable><?php echo $rows['Timestamp']; ?></div></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div contenteditable><?php echo $rows['Name']; ?></div></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div contenteditable><?php echo $rows['Email']; ?></div></td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I also tried to give unique names to divs, but it didn't work. I want to get current values from there if possible.

```
<?php
  if( ! empty($_POST['edit']) ){
   $query = 'UPDATE `asd` SET `Timestamp` = '????' WHERE `UniqueID`='.(int)$id;
   mysql_query($query);
  }
?>
```

Checkboxes work fine when I delete rows from table. Any suggestions ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I used input instead of div and I gave id to them. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several javascript libraries that help with this problem:

- x-editable http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ (bootstrap)
- datatables https://datatables.net/ (jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I solved here:
http://www.abrandao.com/2019/12/saving-contenteditable-html-using-php/

basically, it involves reading the HTML and using PHP parser to exctract the  tag and the update the data